# Polybrush errors in unity 2019.4

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, brush, custom-painting, texturing

i tried to import Polybrush in my unity project on editor 2019.4, and it seems causing many errors, is there a way to correct the errors and use Polybrush again ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved ! Unity seems owning Polybrush now,  when i tried to import Polybrush as a custom package, somehow i had two versions of polybrush in my project, once through the package manager, and one imported directly into the project, i deleted the one imported as a custom package and i imported the verified version from the package manager, That solved the problem.